# error 91 when counting rows on userForm event activate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with some inputs, witch some of them are to be populated automatically (like the ID number) when the user enters the excel or to be re-populated when user adds news items, however it's giving an error when counting the number of rows in a table when opening the workbook.

Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

At the beginning i had all the code showing here in the Initialize event, but when reading more carefully the documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/initialize-event ) it would make sense don't work like this cause the table is not open yet, so i did move the code to the Activate event, but it gives the exact same error. I did move back all the code again to the Initialize event and since i cannot find nothing regarding this particular case i come ask here about it.

```vb
´Workbook code part
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Form_Queimas.Show (vbModeless)
End Sub

´UserForm code part
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set ws = Worksheets("Dados")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TabelaDados")

    Me.Input_ID.Value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1
    Me.Input_Hora_inicial.Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm")

    Me.Input_Freguesia.AddItem "Buarcos e São Julião"
    Me.Input_Freguesia.AddItem "Paião"
    Me.Input_Freguesia.AddItem "Marinha das Ondas"
    Me.Input_Freguesia.AddItem "Ferreira A Nova"
    Me.Input_Freguesia.AddItem "Vila Verde"
    Me.Input_Freguesia.AddItem "Quiaios"
End Sub
```

The idea was to populate automatically the disable input with the table last row number

Thanks in advance

Comment: So `Me.Input_ID.Value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1` is the line that throws the error?

Comment: yes it mate... sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: If the table is empty, `tbl.DataBodyRange` is nothing and as such there are no `Rows` and will throw that error.

Comment: ahh yes .. the table at this moment is empty indeed. I see what you mean. Will check it and report here them ... thanks

Comment: So i am changing to `tbl.ListRows.Count` instead . This one will work always, even if table has zero rows.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listrows
`The ListRows object returned does **not include** the header, total, or Insert rows.`
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: no BigBen just using like this
`Dim tRow As Integer |
tRow = tbl.ListRows.Count |
Me.Input_ID.Value = IIf(tRow = 0, 1, tRow)` | = new line